# python tornado websocket error: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'

Tags: python, tornado

i have the following code, it run well on Tornado <5 but it run into failure if i run it by Tornado>= 5,

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import threading
import tornado.web,tornado.websocket

class thr(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,handler):
        self.handler=handler
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        self.handler.write_message("test")
class ClientWebSocketConnectionHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
            print ("opened")
    def on_message(self, message):
            thr(self).start()    

class MainApplication(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [(r'/User', ClientWebSocketConnectionHandler),]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers,)

TheShieldsWebSocket = MainApplication()
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(TheShieldsWebSocket)
server.listen(8085,'0.0.0.0')
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Error says:`RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'` 
 what the hell wrong with? it looks like it has something to do with the thread.

Comment: Which version of your Python?

Comment: i use python 3.6. i hear about `async` but i don't know must

Comment: I can run your code on `Python 2.x`, haven't try `Python 3.x`.

Comment: what's your tornado ver?

Comment: '4.5.2', but i guess this is no about tornado, it's `threading` issues.

Comment: BTW, you should use `tornado concurrent` instead of multi thread here !

Comment: i don't know how to use this. would you please correct my code the the way you say?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want write a api, this api may be need to wait something before render to the client side! here are serval way to achieve that! as you have use `thread` and this is good but no recommend. so we have invoke concurrent in tornado, you can see detail [here](http://tornado-doc-chs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gen.html).

And here you code can be modify as below:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web,tornado.websocket


class ClientWebSocketConnectionHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
            print ("opened")
    def on_message(self, message):
            self.write_message('test')    

class MainApplication(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [(r'/User', ClientWebSocketConnectionHandler),]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers,)

TheShieldsWebSocket = MainApplication()
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(TheShieldsWebSocket)
server.listen(8085,'0.0.0.0')
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Typical, you will got a `403` error, in that situation you can add a function name as `check_origin`.

```
    # rest of above code
    def check_origin(self, param):
            return True

    def open(self):
            print ("opened")
    def on_message(self, message):
            self.write_message('test')
```

And then if you want you server can handler multi connection, you can use `concurrent way to do that like below :

```
    @gen.coroutine
    def on_message(self, message):
            http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
            response = yield http_client.fetch("http://example.com")
            do_something_with_response(response)
            self.write_message('test')
```

Comment: that thread in my code do something Particular, and i need it. because it's the thread that sends the data to the client.

Comment: sure you can do any thing on this way too

Comment: @alexdayvi first at first, you have to realize that thread just a way which can do something without block master thread, so to make a signal or send something to your client just do it on master but before put the task to your master you have to run it on asynchronous.how you can do it?just do it with concurrent which provide you better than your thread.

Comment: something is processing in the thread and when it comes to a particular result, the result must be sent to the client(s) inside (by) the thread. assume the thread is checking if the time is 5:00 it would send some message to all users. you say that i must run `thr` in async mode?

Comment: @alexdayvi Any processing just can be packed as a function